# Brain Buster ( Comparison of ranking)

Tags: riddle, logical-deduction

- Ali, Saad, and Hassan are all wise.
- Akram, Ali, and Hamza are all industrious.
- Akram, Hassan, and Hamza are all honest.
- Ali, Saad, and Hamza are all sportsmen.

**Which of them are not wise, but is a sportsman?**

1. Ali
2. Akram
3. Hassan
4. Hamza

Comment: This is painfully simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is

> **4 — Hamza**. 
> If we call the set of all sportsmen $S = \{\textrm{Ali}, \textrm{Saad}, \textrm{Hamza}\}$ and the set of all wise $W = \{\textrm{Ali}, \textrm{Saad}, \textrm{Hassan}\}$, we can deduce that $S \land (\neg W) = \{\textrm{Hamza}\}$. Therefore, Hamza is the only one who is a sportsman but is not wise.

Comment: My answer seems awfully simple... am I missing something vital?